# Web-scraping script is not finding element given its class name. Unsure what I'm missing in this code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Problem Description:**

I'm trying to get the URL of an image on this page: [https://www2.hm.com/en_us/productpage.1109917007.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

This first picture (pic #1) shows the desired image highlighted in blue + its class name. When you click on that image, you then get its fullscreen image (pic #2), whose URL I'm trying to get.

I wrote the code so that it clicks on the image and then gets the URL of the fullscreen image. But, I am not getting any output. What am I missing here?

[pic #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otCgZ.jpg)

[pic #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VojeQ.jpg)

**What I tried (code below):** I tried opening the page to the product listing, getting the element of the desired image by its class, clicking on the image, and then retrieving its url.

**What I expected:** I expected for this code to retrieve the desired images' URL and print "Found Image!"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import time


def web_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--verbose")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920, 1200")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver

driver = web_driver()
driver.get('https://www2.hm.com/en_us/productpage.1109917007.html')
delay = 5
image_urls = set()
thumbnails = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-detail-thumbnail-image")
print(thumbnails)
for img in thumbnails:
  try:
    img.click()
    time.sleep(delay)
  except:
    continue
  images = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "current fullscreen-image-modal-image")
  for image in images:
    if image.get_attribute('src') and 'http' in image.get_attribute('src'):
      image_urls.add(image.get_attribute('src'))
      print('Found image!')
      continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info about the product is embedded inside `<script>` element, so you can use `re`/`ast.literal_eval` to parse it:

```py
import json
import re
from ast import literal_eval

import requests

product_id = "1109917007"  # <-- this is from URL, last 3 characters is color variant(?)
url = "https://www2.hm.com/en_us/productpage.1109917007.html"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0"
}

html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
html_text = re.sub(r"isDesktop \? '([^']+)' : '([^']+)'", r"'\g<1>'", html_text)
html_text = re.sub(r"true", r"True", html_text)
html_text = re.sub(r"false", r"False", html_text)
html_text = re.sub(r"null", r"None", html_text)

data = re.search(r"productArticleDetails = (\{.*?\});", html_text, flags=re.S).group(1)
data = literal_eval(data)

# print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for k in data:
    if k.startswith(product_id[:-3]):
        print("Color:", data[k]["name"])
        print("-" * 80)
        for i in data[k]["images"]:
            print("https:" + i["fullscreen"])
        print()
```

Prints:

```
Color: Black
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F98%2F2d%2F982d385e56684698281797aaccccddd2fbb24000.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F5d%2F5e%2F5d5e407e0d81f539f191f66832b80041e5cdb4ed.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F05%2Ff3%2F05f369cfae2758a389c53279860e37b1cc491163.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Fa6%2F9d%2Fa69db194655f2726ae046f8431b26a51223a06de.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Fe3%2Fef%2Fe3ef8cfda92d48f3462ced35b6b20e1701175610.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Fea%2F4d%2Fea4db6703dacf6d08a5096fd35d64f22635129a7.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Fcb%2F26%2Fcb26ad968570dfd16ce1b15a23fbfe745600c460.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F99%2Faf%2F99af20288ff42b2b37150e3f9e08cf4c41779d46.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Fff%2F81%2Fff811ffbce5597233b7411c224ecf026f7a9e458.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BDESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B2%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F0b%2Fd0%2F0bd00adae7d1feb9745ec3094783e18984d679f8.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BDESCRIPTIVEDETAIL%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B2%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]

Color: Green
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F34%2F30%2F343092fe2836f8180599906a22aedfe796ace04f.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F79%2F10%2F791029a9dbd1ba9d7f350f7dc6b73d7f0fd3c50f.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Fb0%2F84%2Fb084247de8696d49d0b7f1196283a37738815b4d.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Fb2%2F98%2Fb298c1d2b2eb7b9de8c8b71c838c3a79f636ad25.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F2f%2Fd9%2F2fd9d76b9f220be376581694315e63df21f62e3b.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F01%2F66%2F016612842a3217f82189b2d8e9284a81d0f11f0c.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5Bladies_dresses_longsleevedress%5D%2Ctype%5BDESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B2%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F57%2F08%2F5708c1a6ef58bc2d9d6149360de38b24866aa9ee.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5Bladies_dresses_longsleevedress%5D%2Ctype%5BDESCRIPTIVEDETAIL%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B2%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]

Color: Burgundy
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F77%2F1a%2F771a7c54e25f342b23993d67a03da7ef3a7f0227.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F78%2F25%2F782577fbee3259e57daebacd77deae987952dd52.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F3b%2F9c%2F3b9c910350c73703e9fa19c04954469bc5092ee0.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Ff2%2F7a%2Ff27ac48abcd1fd3af4930625349db11e4304e8e5.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F9e%2F1b%2F9e1bca254c6cabaf0924e4f12b9d5c3de0a5e079.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5Bladies_dresses_longsleevedress%5D%2Ctype%5BDESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B2%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F13%2F33%2F13337567931c75ca1a59b4c02dddf6f45b61ffb2.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5Bladies_dresses_longsleevedress%5D%2Ctype%5BDESCRIPTIVEDETAIL%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B2%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]

Color: Light beige
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Fad%2F79%2Fad79561ecb2ab9fdb3c77cd0aff996628b63bd6a.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F3c%2F79%2F3c790c4ae0949a1690da550293b2c2f57c01772c.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F17%2F13%2F17137a1449b12fc42a8c69042408e6d57e912ea3.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Fde%2Fe9%2Fdee94a36a5898f9008680f79070bf271bf6d5790.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5Bladies_dresses_longsleevedress%5D%2Ctype%5BDESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B2%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2Fc1%2F8c%2Fc18c37d8f1ae19071002165b988087c1984e075d.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5Bladies_dresses_longsleevedress%5D%2Ctype%5BDESCRIPTIVEDETAIL%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B2%5D&call=url[file:/product/fullscreen]
```

Comment: Kesley Your response was beyond helpful. Thank you. Question: is there a way to do this same thing with selenium? Mainly curious because that's what I've been practicing with so far (new to webscraping).

Comment: @Danny_webb I don't have much experience with selenium, but I see no reason why it couldn't be done (but how, that's other question). But the rule of thumb is - if it can be done with plain `requests` then it's better (memory and resource wise).